# Kubernetes Pod - Application log

Tags: logging, kubernetes

I have a requirement to extract my application log which is available under /var/etc/logs directory.  How do I extract this from K8 pods?

Tried kubectl exec but didnt help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logs in Kubernetes for pods which are deployed using deployments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48403638/logs-in-kubernetes-for-pods-which-are-deployed-using-deployments)

Comment: You can also use filebeat to stream the logs to ELK

Answer (score 4):

The purest and simplest way to get the application log from your pod is using [kubectl cp](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp)

```
kubectl cp <pod-name>:/var/etc/logs logs
```

This will copy the pod logs to your local machine.

*However..*

That's probably not a good long term solution. I'd recommend:

- Outputting the logs to stdout inside the container, which would mean `kubectl logs` would become availabla ro you
- Using a [fluentd as a sidecar](https://blog.powerupcloud.com/kubernetes-pod-management-using-fluentd-as-a-sidecar-container-and-prestop-lifecycle-hook-part-iv-428b5f4f7fc7?gi=675105c38b0f) container to manage the logs

More information can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/)

Answer (score 2):

Besides the [`Fluentd`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#sidecar-container-with-a-logging-agent) sidecar option described in the other answers, you can also add simple [`tail -n+1 -f /var/etc/logs`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#streaming-sidecar-container) sidecar to output your logs to stdout:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container
    image: yourimage
    volumeMounts:
    - name: varlog
      mountPath: /var/log
  - name: logs
    image: busybox
    args: [/bin/sh, -c, 'tail -n+1 -f /var/etc/logs']
    volumeMounts:
    - name: varlog
      mountPath: /var/log
  volumes:
  - name: varlog
    emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: This is actually a great way to ductape an existing app to behave as you need it to until you get the time to fix the logging

Answer (score 0):

You might need a log collector like fluentd.

k8s itself won't persist log for you.

If you are using GKE, stackdriver might be an approach (heard, never tried).